# How to deploy using Git - Remote repo is not recognized as a Git repertory

Tags: git, ssh, deployment

I try to deploy a branch of my git repository to my LAMP server.
I have initialized a Git repo on my server:

```
$ ssh user@ip.address
...
user@server.domain [test]# git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/user/public_html/.../test/.git/
```

On my local repo, I have added the remote path and tried to push a branch:

```
git remote add test ssh://user@ip.address/public_html/.../test
git push test myBranch
```

Here is what I get:

```
fatal: '/public_html/.../test' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can someone help me or have a better way to do it?

Comment: I also tried with user@server.domain [test]# git init --bare and it's still not working

Comment: I found my mistake I forgot the "~". So the remote url have to be git remote add test ssh://user@ip.address/~/public_html/.../test